# Using Web API 2 built in login features - AngularJS and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a MVC with AngularJS website that connects to a Web API 2 project.

I am trying to get a login and register page working.

I have followed the modules in this pluralsight video - [angular-web-api-front-back](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angular-web-api-front-back) however I need to modify it slightly to fit better with the structure of my website and store more details in the user table.

I am getting the following error when I try and register a user.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerUser' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.RegisterUser (http://localhost:44260/Scripts/MyProject/Controllers/RegisterController.js:14:33)
```

My Code: 
LoginController.js

```
var LoginController = function ($scope, $window, UserAccount, CurrentUser) {

$scope.Register = function() {
    $window.location.href = '/home/register';
};

$scope.isLoggedIn = function () {
    return CurrentUser.getProfile().isLoggedIn;
};
$scope.message = '';

$scope.registerUser = function () {
    $scope.model.confirmPassword = $scope.model.password;

    UserAccount.registration.registerUser($scope.model,
        function (data) {
            $scope.model.confirmPassword = "";
            $scope.message = "... Registration successful";
            $scope.login();
        },
        function (response) {
            $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
            $scope.message = response.statusText + "\r\n";
            if (response.data.exceptionMessage)
                $scope.message += response.data.exceptionMessage;

            // Validation errors
            if (response.data.modelState) {
                for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
                    $scope.message += response.data.modelState[key] + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        });
}

$scope.login = function () {
    $scope.model.grant_type = "password";
    $scope.model.userName = $scope.model.email;

    UserAccount.login.loginUser($scope.model,
        function (data) {
            $scope.message = "";
            $scope.model.password = "";
            CurrentUser.setProfile($scope.model.userName, data.access_token);
        },
        function (response) {
            $scope.model.password = "";
            $scope.message = response.statusText + "\r\n";
            if (response.model.exceptionMessage)
                $scope.message += response.model.exceptionMessage;

            if (response.model.error) {
                $scope.message += response.model.error;
            }
        });
}

};

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window', 'UserAccount', 'CurrentUser'];
```

UserAccount.js:

```
var UserAccount = function userAccount($resource, ApiAddress) {
    return function () {
        registration: $resource(ApiAddress + "/api/Account/Register", null,
        {
            'registerUser': { method: 'POST' }
        });
        login: $resource(ApiAddress + "/Token", null,
        {
            'loginUser': {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                    var str = [];
                    for (var d in data)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" +
                            encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
                    return str.join("&");
                }
            }
        });
    }};
 UserAccount.$inject = ['$resource', 'ApiAddress'];
```

CurrentUser.js

```
var CurrentUser = function() {
return function () {
    var profile = {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        username: "",
        token: ""
    };

    var setProfile = function (username, token) {
        profile.username = username;
        profile.token = token;
        profile.isLoggedIn = true;
        return profile;
    };

    var getProfile = function () {
        return profile;
    }

    return {
        setProfile: setProfile,
        getProfile: getProfile
    }
}};
CurrentUser.$inject = [];
```